# Simple HttpClient in C# ReadAsStringAsync returns empty content on .ASPX sites

Tags: httpclient

I have a simple GetAsync and Read for website.  Works fine for static HTML sites.  Returns empty content when going to a site with .aspx.

```
                    var myUri = new Uri("http://www.aamusports.com/staff.aspx");
                    var response= await  myClient.GetAsync(myUri);  
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I've tried variations on ConfigureAwait, I'm always getting back empty content. I'm believing the ASPX has to resolve on the server side before I proceed, but how does my program know when it's completely resolved to continue?

### Update

Some Aspx pages resolve, and some return zero content. Still can't tell why.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?  An example of a page that returns zero content from Httpclient is "http://www.aamusports.com/staff.aspx".  One that returns fine with content is "http://www.destinationathlete.com/teams/find.aspx".  I've looked at fillder, and postman and I don't see anything that stands out.

Answer (score 4):

After comparing fiddlers request parms, I started setting them on my httpclient, and found that setting user-agent caused the content to be populated.

```
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Custom");
```

Never saw that documented anywhere but made it work on multiple aspx pages.
Hope it helps next person.
Update:
I still had some websites not displaying so I just put the user-agent in fiddler as shown and it allowed most/all of the websites to resolve.

```
> myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
> NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");
```